# setImageResources from an activity.java to change the image resource from another activity.java

Tags: java, android

I am making two activities, FirstActivity.java which contain a listView with onClickListener that start the SecondActivity.java and change the image resource of an ImageView that contained in SecondActivity.java when clicked. I set this code in FirstActivity.java :

```
Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1)
final ImageView image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1)
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            image1.setImageResource(R.drawable.imagexxx);
        }
    });
}
```

But when I run the application and press the button, the application crashed. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: What exception did it crash with?

Comment: Generally, you cannot access one Activity instance from another Activity, and especially not second Activity's UI (view)

Comment: if you need to access first class UI in second class better to pass android Context to second class through constructor.

Comment: How to pass the context to the second class? Sorry I'm still new in android programming.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1) 
    final ImageView image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1)
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //set Image
        image1.setImageResource(R.drawable.imagexxx);
         //then start another activity
        Intent i = new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);

    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've tried your suggestion but same thing still happened. I've found out that I need to use getExtra in my Intent to pass the control to another activity. But I have no idea of how to do that so I can set the image resource in secondActivity. Any suggestion?

Comment: What actually R.drawable.imagexxx is? a png or xml?

Comment: R.drawable.imagexxx is a png